# Convert presence/absence table to keyword list by group

Tags: sql-server, concatenation, calculated-columns

I have a list of parameter codes that are associated with a variety of keywords. I want to store/maintain this as a presence absence matrix / table where each column represents a keyword, and each row is a parameter. Y/(null) would indicate applicability of each keyword to each parameter, as such:

| parameter | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 |  |  | Y |  |  | Y |  |  |
| 23456 |  |  | Y |  |  | Y | Y |  |
| 78912 | Y |  |  |  |  |  |  | Y |
| 78187 | Y |  |  |  |  |  |  | Y |
| 89473 |  |  | Y | Y |  |  |  |  |
| 73292 |  |  | Y |  | Y |  | Y |  |
| 52891 |  |  | Y |  | Y |  | Y |  |
| 80636 |  | Y |  |  |  |  |  | Y |
| 47350 |  |  | Y |  | Y |  |  |  |
| 29450 |  |  | Y |  |  | Y | Y |  |

However, for ease of use on the query end, I want to then convert this (dynamically as a calculated table or column) to a string containing only the applicable keywords for each parameter, as such:

| parameter | keywords |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | C, F |
| 23456 | C, F, G |
| 78912 | A, H, |
| 78187 | A, H, |
| 89473 | C, D |
| 73292 | C, E, G |
| 52891 | C, E, G |
| 80636 | B, H, |
| 47350 | C, E |
| 29450 | C, F, G |

This summary column can be stored as a calculated column as part of the above table if possible. Also, I need it to be dynamic in terms of the number of columns as it needs to convert ALL columns except the original parameter column to the latter form.

I'm at a loss on what might work for this. My skills aren't that strong yet.

Comment: This is called dynamic unpivot + some string_aggregation. There are a lot of previous questions regarding that subject that you might want to peruse. Usually it's a mistake to do this, and means your design is incorrect. You should've had a Parameter, Keyword table instead

Comment: So are you saying you *don't* know what columns your table will have..? In truth, it looks like you would be better off changing your design; instead of columns `A`,`B`,`C`, etc, you should have a column called `keyword` that has values like `'A'`,`'B'`,`'C'`, etc, and you have 1 row per keyword for a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you need to do two things here. First, you need to get your data in a format where you can treat all those arbitrary columns as a single column to work with. Basically, you want a table which has `param`, `columnname`, `value`.

The tricky part is though since you don't know the column names in advance, you have to make use of dynamic sql; basically constructing a string which gets executed as literal code. This is a kind of dangerous thing to do if you don't know what you're doing with it. If you plan to tinker with this or use dynamic sql elsewhere, make sure you understand vulnerabilities to something called an [injection attack](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection).

Here's the setup data. Note, I used `bit` fields instead of string "Y/N" values. but the same logic works. Just replace the reference to the value `1` with `'y`' and you'll be golden.

```
drop table if exists #table
select *
into #Table
from
(
    select Param = 12345, A = 0, B = 0, C = 1, D = 0, E = 0, F = 1, G = 0, H =0 union all
    select 23456, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 union all
    select 78912, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 union all
    select 78187, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 union all
    select 89473, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 union all
    select 73292, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 union all
    select 82891, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 union all
    select 80636, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 union all
    select 47350, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 union all
    select 29450, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0
) a
```

To get our list of columns we want to "unpivot", we'll select them from the metadata table `sys.columns`. Note, since I'm using a temporary table, I'm referencing `tempdb.sys.columns`. If your data lives elsewhere, change the database accordingly (or just set a `Use {mydb}` statement at the top of your script).

And here's the list of columns from the table. Notice the use of `quotename`. This escapes any square brackets and wraps the value in square brackets. Although it's unlikely you'll have a column name which contains injectable code, this also makes you safe if you have a column with, say, spaces in it. So it's good to use regardless.

```
declare @Columns nvarchar(max)

select @Columns = string_agg(quotename(name), ',')
from tempdb.sys.columns
where object_id = object_id('tempdb.dbo.#table')
and name != 'Param'
-- Here's what we generated above
select @Columns
```

Now it's time to construct our pivot. We're doing three things here:

1. Unpivoting the data to get it in the format `param, value, name` where `value` is the bit value of the column, and `name` is the column name we're going to concatenate
2. We're filtering the data to only those rows where the `value` is 1 (i.e. "Y", or True), since those are the values we want to concatenate.
3. We're grouping by the `Param`, and using `string_agg` again to form each row with a bit value of 1.

```
    declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = concat
    ('
        select Param, string_agg(Name, '','') within group (order by Name)
        from #table s
        unpivot (Value for Name in (', @Columns, ')) u
        where Value = 1
        group by Param
    ')    
    select @sql -- if you want to see the code that was generated and executed
    exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Results:

| Param | Keywords |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | C,F |
| 23456 | C,F,G |
| 29450 | C,F,G |
| 47350 | C,E |
| 73292 | C,E,G |
| 78187 | A,H |
| 78912 | A,H |
| 80636 | B,H |
| 82891 | C,E,G |
| 89473 | C,D |

Answer (score 0):

Here is option that will dynamically unpivot your data without having to specify all the columns... just the one to "exclude"

**Example**

```
 Select [parameter]
       ,[keywords] = string_agg([key],',')
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( Select * 
                From  OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )) 
                Where [Key] not in ('parameter','Other','Columns','ToExclude')
             ) B
 Group By [parameter]
```